# How does this code C# translate in C++ using Windows Cryptorgraphic API?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, cryptoapi

How would you translate this C# in C++ using the Windows Cryptographic API? I'm a newbie in this field and that API looks quite complex...

```
Rijndael aes = Rijndael.Create();
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cryptedText);
byte[] decryptedText = new byte[0x10];

using (CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(decryptKey, new byte[0x10]), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    decrypt.Read(decryptedText, 0, 0x10);
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the managed version in C++ as seen on this MSDN page, look for the Example section

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx#Y2371